# Optimize iteration of 2-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, optimization, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to optimize a Google Apps Script which iterates over the rows in a spreadsheet in reverse (bottom to top). The script checks the 1st cell in the row if its past 15 days and also checks the 12th column for the string "Yes", the row is moved from one sheet to another if both conditions are true.

The trouble I am having is that I am exceeding the allotted time (6 minutes) iterating over all the data which is 2500 rows and expecting to grow much larger.

I am sure similar questions have been answered here many times, but I am unable apply the solutions I found here given my current programming skill level. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

This is the format of the sheet:

```
 1st column                 12th column
+-----------+-----/ /-----+-------------+
|  Date     |             | Refunded?   |
+-----------+-----/ /-----+-------------+
| 8/29/2017 |             |     YES     |
+-----------+-----/ /-----+-------------+
| 9/26/2017 |             |      NO     |
+-----------+-----/ /-----+-------------+
```

This is the script:

```
function myFunction() {
  // get compare date (15 days from current date 
  var compareDate = new Date().getTime() - (15 * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

  // get sheets in spreadsheet
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
  var arr = [];

  // get 1st sheet data
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var r = values.length;

  // logic
  while (r >= 1) {
    if (values[r] && values[r][0].getTime() < compareDate && values[r][12].toLowerCase() == "yes" ) {        
      arr.push(values[r])
      sheet.deleteRow(r + 1)
    }
    r--;
  }

  target.getRange(target.getLastRow() + 1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr.reverse())
}
```

If I comment out the following line of code "sheet.deleteRow(r + 1)" the script completes almost instantly so this seems like the culprit that is slowing down the execution of the script. Would there be a more efficient solution to this problem?

Comment: May try two temporary arrays one is for the rows you want to keep and the other is for the rows you want to delete.  Then just add the delete array to the second page as you do and clear the first page and setValues() on the first page with the keeper array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting deeper with Ruben's idea about deleting multiple rows at once. It would be a good idea to sort your data before you actually start comparing so that all the oldest "yes" values are at the bottom.

To check it, I set up a sheet with 25000 records with:

```
function fillSheet() {
  var yesNo = ['yes', 'no'];
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 25000; i++) {
    array[i] = [];
    var rand = yesNo[Math.floor(Math.random() * yesNo.length)];
    array[i].push(new Date(2016, 1, i), i, i + 1, i + 2, i + 3, i + 4, i + 5, i + 6, i + 7, i + 8, i + 9, i + 10, rand);
  }
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
}
```

Then I've modified your function so that it firstly sorts the data range by yes/no and by date and then does the checks (starting from the top this time).

```
function myFunction() {
  // get compare date (15 days from current date 
  var compareDate = new Date().getTime() - (15 * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

  // get sheets in spreadsheet
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
  var arr = [];

  // get 1st sheet data
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  //sorting the range without the header row firstly by yes/no values and then by dates to make sure the oldest yes value are at the bottom and only then getting the values
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, lastCol).sort([{column: 13, ascending: true}, {column: 1, ascending: false}]);  
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, lastCol).getValues();
  var r = 0;
  var firstMatch = 0;

  // logic
  while (r < values.length) {
    if (values[r] && values[r][0].getTime() < compareDate && values[r][12].toLowerCase() == "yes" ) {
      //looking for the first match which will be used in deleting the rows
      if (firstMatch === 0) {
        firstMatch = r + 1; 
      }
      else if (firstMatch > 0 && firstMatch > r) {
        firstMatch = r + 1;
      } 
      arr.push(values[r])
    }
    r++;
  }
  if (firstMatch > 0) {
    target.getRange(target.getLastRow() + 1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr); //this will insert the array twice in my case anв i'm not sure why
    sheet.deleteRows(firstMatch, values.length - firstMatch + 2); //+2 is empirical to make sure all rows are removed; not really sure where it comes from
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, lastCol).sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
  }
}
```

This way, it'll take around 4 seconds to run.

There's a couple of glitches, though:

- it tries to insert the resulting array twice into the target sheet, though it apparently shouldn't. Maybe has sth to do with Vivaldi browser I'm using now don't know.
- the empirical firstMatch, values.length - firstMatch + 2 - again not sure why it should +2 but without that it won't remove the 2 last rows.

Hope it helps anyway.

Comment: thank you very much for your help with this script. I am in the process of testing it with my data and everything seems to be working as should be. I will continue to test to see if I see an anomalies. Again, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than deleting one row by iteration, delete all the rows at once at the end of your script by using [deleteRows(rowPosition, howMany)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteRows(Integer,Integer)). The line of code could be something like the following one:

```
sheet.deleteRows(2, values.length - 1);
```

Comment: Hi Rubén, thank you for taking the time to write a reply to my question. I am trying to implement what you suggested I am just wondering how I can use the "deleteRow" method if the rows insequential (i.e. row 100, 104, 120, 122, etc.)?

Comment: @danslik: I think that it could be a lot easier and faster to add the required rows to a new sheet.